# Create new customer via OCAPI and send password to customer

Tags: commerce-cloud

I know that a can create a new costumer via OCAPI call:

`POST https://hostname:port/dw/data/v19_3/customer_lists/{list_id}/customers`

But in the Credentials document there is no password to be specified or a setting for the "Send Password Update Mail" option I have in the BM.

How can I notify the customer that the account has been created so that he can change/set their password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `dw.ocapi.data.customer_list.customers.afterPOST` hook you can trigger an email with a password reset token link within it. Alternatively, you could create the link and return it in a [flash message](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/19.3/usage/Flash.html?cp=0_12_2_11) or via a [custom property](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/19.3/usage/CustomProperties.html?cp=0_12_2_7) in the response JSON.

In order to retrieve the password reset token, you'd need to call the [`createResetPasswordToken()`](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/class_dw_customer_Credentials.html#dw_customer_Credentials_createResetPasswordToken_DetailAnchor) method of the `dw.customer.Credentials` class instance that represents the Customer Profile's credentials. This can be retrieved in the `customers.afterPOST` hook like so:

```
const Status = require('dw.system.Status');

function handleAfterPOST(customer, responseObj, customerListID) {
  let credentials = customer.getProfile().getCredentials();
  let token;

  if (!empty(credentails)) {
    token = credentials.createResetPasswordToken();
  }

  if (!empty(token)) {
    // add token to response object, send an email, or something like that...
    responseObj.c_reset_token = token;
    return new Status(Satus.OK);
  } else {
    return new Status(Status.ERROR);
  }
}
```

Of course, your hook handler would need to be [registered in your hooks.json](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/19.3/usage/Customization.html?cp=0_12_2_6#Customization19.3__ExtensionPointRegistration) file.

Comment: Thank you for your extended answer and the example, I might have imagined that being easier, but I'll get to work trying your suggesting.